# type 'List<(String?) => String?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<(dynamic) => String?>'

Tags: forms, flutter, dictionary, dart, types

So I wanted to create my custom form with custom form field controllers. Each MyFormControl instance has two generic types ViewType (for widget purposes) and DataType (for Json purposes).
But in MyForm I want to use this generic type as dynamic, because I don't care what type it's in runtype as it can hold different value type for each specific field (for example, String, int, DateTime...).

But why I get type **'List<(String?) => String?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<(dynamic) => String?>'** error when it seems logical - in MyForm I want to use value which type I don't know and don't care, but I do know what I want to do with it.

Even such trivial line as **print(control.validators.runtimeType);** doesn't work. Can someone explain this generic type and dynamic behaviour?

```
  abstract class MyForm {
      final Map<String, MyFormControl<dynamic, dynamic>> form;
      final Map<String, String> errors = <String, String>{};
      final List<FormFieldValidator<dynamic>> formValidators;
      MyForm(this.form, {this.formValidators = const []});
    
      bool validate() {
        bool valid = true;
        form.forEach((key, control) {
          // final validators = control.validators;
          print(control.validators.runtimeType);
          // for (var validator in control.validators) {
          //   final errorText = validator(control.value);
          //   if (errorText != null) {
          //     errors.putIfAbsent(key, () => errorText);
          //     valid = false;
          //     break;
          //   }
          // }
        });
        return valid;
      }
    }
class MyFormControl<ViewT, DataT> {
  final ViewT? value;
  final List<FormFieldValidator<ViewT>> validators;
  final List<Future<FormFieldValidator<ViewT>>> asyncValidators;
  final MyFormConverter<ViewT, DataT>? converter;

  MyFormControl({
    this.value,
    this.validators = const [],
    this.asyncValidators = const [],
    this.converter,
  });
}

/// this function is from flutter sdk form.dart file
typedef FormFieldValidator<T> = String? Function(T? value);
```

I even tried replace validators with **final List<String? Function(ViewT? value)> validators;** it still gives the same error.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing which line the error occurs on.

Comment: print(control.validators.runtimeType); here